# sqrt function fortran 90 error

Tags: fortran90, sqrt

I am trying to handle sqrt but somehow I cannot understand why when compiling this program, there goes a segmentation fault error. I have detected that it is because of the sqrt. But how can I manage to use sqrt in these type of formulations without mistaking?

```
SUBROUTINE constructImages(image,w,w_b,x_w)
    USE cellConst
    USE simParam, ONLY: xDim, yDim, obstX, obstY, obstR,L_max
    USE D2Q9Const, ONLY: v

implicit none
integer, INTENT(INOUT):: image(yDim,xDim),w_b(yDim,xDim),w(yDim,xDim)
double precision, dimension(L_max,0:1),     INTENT(INOUT):: x_w
integer:: x,y,i,cont_L
double precision::x2,y2
!Disk Shape
do x = 1, xDim
    do y = 1, yDim
        if (((x-obstX)**2.0d0 + (y-obstY)**2.0d0) <= (obstR**2.0d0) ) then
    image(y,x) = wall
    w(y,x) = wall
    end if
    end do
end do
do x = 1, xDim
    do y = 3, yDim-2
    do i= 1,8
    if ((w(y,x) == fluid) .and. (w(y+v(i,1),x+v(i,0)) == wall)) then
        w_b(y,x) = 2
    end if
    end do
end do
end do
do x = 1,xDim
do y = 3, yDim-2
    if (w_b(y,x) == 2) then
    w_b(y,x) = wall
    w(y,x) = wall
    image(y,x) = wall
    end if
end do
end do

x_w = 0.0d0     !Lagrangian vector for boundary exact position
cont_L = 0

do x = 1, xDim
    do y = 1, yDim
        do i = 1, 8
        if ((w(y+v(i,1),x+v(i,0)) == fluid) .and. (w_b(y,x) == wall)) then 
        cont_L = cont_L +1
```

.           x_w(cont_L,0) = x2 - ((x-obstX)^2.0d0 + (y-obstY)^2.0d0)**^0.5d0** - obstR

.           x_w(cont_L,1) = y2 - ((x-obstX)^2.0d0 + (y-obstY)^2.0d0)**^0.5d0** - obstR

```
 !          write(*,*) x2,y2
 !          write(*,*) x_w(cont_L,0),x_w(cont_L,1)
        end if
        end do
    end do
end do
 END SUBROUTINE constructImages
```

Please, let me know if more information is required,

sincerely,

Albert P

PD, the 3 integer eulerian meshes are 0 / 1 2D meshes where 1 is assigned to a wall, which is delimited by a rounded disk, w_b(y,x) are the boundary points,  w(y,x) are the whole disk points and x_w I want to set a langrangian vector of the discretized exact position for the obstacle. Don't really need to understand this.

Comment: Does it work (not segfault) for any values at all?

Comment: Here the problem occurs after compilation. I don't understand why, but It seems that when I take out the square root, placed in bold on the problem statement, it magically performs fine. 
wallyk, what do you want me to change in this case? can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Seg faults are very strange things.  The exact point of occurrence is not easy to find.  You remove the square root and the fault goes away?  Believe it or not, this does *not* prove that the root is causing the fault.  I can't see how raising something to a power is *in and of itself* going to give a seg fault.  On the other hand, that 0 index in array x_w in the same line looks a little suspicious.  I would triple check that you are passing the x_w array you should be passing, and that the subroutine recognizes it as such.

Comment: One more thing, I think using the FORTRAN sqrt() intrinsic is going to be at least slightly more efficient than raising a number to the power 1/2.  Others who know more about this might disagree, though.

Comment: Segfaults are far from strange - try a debugger and you will see exactly where the problem occurs. 

Without the whole of your code, you're asking us to analyze and think out something that can be answered by a debugging tool by you in seconds. Give one a go, and see what you find.

Comment: Hi David, could you facilitate me  where I can get an good debugger for f90. BTW, I am using linux. Thanks anyway!
bob.sacamento, where do you refer of x_w array 0 in the same line??

Comment: Have to partially disagree with the debugger comment.  I have seen seg faults that disappear once the code is compiled for debugging, and so they can't be found with a debugger.  Not always, but often enough for real concern.

Comment: @Albert Pa: I am looking at the regular text line btwn the the code snips: `x_w(cont_L,0) = x2 - ((x-obstX)^2.0d0 + (y-obstY)^2.0d0)^0.5d0 - obstR`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually an array index which was under 1 in w, and there were multiple problems that somehow derived to that error when setting sqrt.

```
do x = 1, xDim
    do y = 1, yDim
        do i = 1, 8
if ((w(y,x) == fluid) .and. (w(y+v(i,1),x+v(i,0)) == wall))
.....
```

here I state that w goes >1, and then it gets out of the bounds.
I have solved the problem not letting the integers go below 1 and over yDim, and this with all the routines, and I have detected that problem with a check-bounce while executing the code.

Thank you all of you anyway. That was a tough one!!

Albert P